# How do I stop one pivot table from affecting a chart created from a different pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I am working on processing average CPU loads on some of my servers in Excel 2013. I have my raw data in a table named RawData which contains the CPU load and a timestamp in each row. From RawData I created two pivot tables (loadDaily and loadHourly). In loadDaily, I set the timestamp as a row lable, and set it to group by Days, Hours, Minutes and created a nice chart of my CPU load from it. Now the problem I am having is when I try to group the timestamp field in loadHourly by Hours only, it also applies the grouping to my other pivot table (loadDaily) and my pivot chart linked to that. How do I make the grouping on the timestamp field only apply to loadHourly?

Comment: Okay, I answered my own question after toying with it some more. I noticed that after creating my initial groups, in the Pivot Table field list there were new fields (Hours and Days). In my second table, instead of adding the raw timestamp field to it I found out I can use the Hours field that was created when I made my group for the first time.

Comment: you may add it as answer (after some time) and accept. This will be useful for future askers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I answered my own question after toying with it some more. I noticed that after creating my initial groups, in the Pivot Table field list there were new fields (Hours and Days). In my second table, instead of adding the raw timestamp field to it I found out I can use the Hours field that was created when I made my group for the first time.